# If $A,B$ are self-adjoint and $A+B\ge 0$, then $A_+-B_-,\ B_+-A_-\ge 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Let $0\le X\in B(H)$ ($X$ is a positive bounded linear operator on a Hilbert $H$). 
 Assume that there are self-adjoint $A,B\in B(H)$ such that $X=A+B$. I am thinking how to decompose $X$ into some positive operators depending on $A,B$. My idea is $$X=A+B=A_+-A_- +B_+-B_- =(A_+-B_-)+ (B_+-A_-).$$ However,  I don't know how to show that  $A_+-B_-$, $B_+-A_-\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.
Define 
$$
B = \frac12\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1} = \pmatrix{0 & -1\\ -1 & 0}
$$
with 
$$
B^- = - \frac12\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1} \pmatrix{0&0\\0&-1}\pmatrix{1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1} = -\pmatrix{ -1 & -1\\ -1 & -1}.
$$
Set
$$
A=\pmatrix{3&0\\0&1} = A^+.
$$
Then 
$$
A+B =\pmatrix{3&-1\\-1&1}
$$
is positive definite,
$$
A^+-B^-=\pmatrix{2&-1\\-1&0}
$$
is indefinite.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, I think I need to find some other ways.